# Highchart: stacked grouped column

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

i tried this:
http://jsfiddle.net/3kpTK/1/
In this example i have several two groups that contain two types of information: "move" and "delete.

```
series: [{
            name: "group1",
            data: [50,20,30,50],
            stack: "move"
        }, {
            name: "group1",
            data: [10,23,0,52],
            stack:"delete"
        },{
            name: "group2",
            data: [50,20,30,50],
            stack: "move"
        }, {
            name: "group2",
            data: [10,23,0,52],
            stack:"delete"
        }
```

Highchart puts them into two different groups with the same name and different colors. I want to put in the same group, columns that are on different stacks but with same name. How can i do?

The output that i want in this example is formed by the two series "group1" and "group2".

EDIT:
This is my real case
[image: example]

In the legend the groups are double, for example batch production(move) is purple and batch production(delete) is light blue. I want only one "batch poduction" with one color for both(move,delete)

Comment: What is your expected output? You have 4 series. Group 1 - move and delete. Group 2 - move and delete. So, you are going to get 4 series in output.

Comment: So you would like to have 2 series, but in two stacks? Have you any mockup?

Comment: I added more information to better explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the same colors, you need to set them directly in series options. Then to get in legend only group 1 and 2 add ID's to the series and link next series within the same group. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3kpTK/2/

```
    series: [{
        id: 'g1',
        color: 'blue',
        name: "group1",
        data: [50,20,30,50],
        stack: "move"
    }, {
        linkedTo: 'g1',
        color: 'blue',
        name: "group1",
        data: [10,23,0,52],
        stack:"delete"
    },{
        id: 'g2',
        color: 'green',
        name: "group2",
        data: [50,20,30,50],
        stack: "move"
    }, {
        linkedTo: 'g2',
        color: 'green',
        name: "group2",
        data: [10,23,0,52],
        stack:"delete"
    }]
```